# Thread would not start in Application_Start in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

This, IMO, is weird behavior or I must be doing something wrong, the latter being high probability.

I am initiating a thread inside `Application_Start` event of ASP.NET.

I did search on the net and it seems that it is possible to spawn and run a thread inside this event.

Somehow I am not able to achieve it.

My event is as below

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some code here

    //Logging to a file. This is working fine

    try
    {
        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartJob));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Name = "BackgroundChecker";
        thread.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //No error here
    }
}

private void StartJob()
{
    //Tried to log to a file, same as above, but not able to do so
}
```

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to place a breakpoint in the beginning of your `StartJob`? Does it enter this method?

Comment: Breakpoints doesn't work in Application_Start (too much of hard work to get it going :)). Plus I am running this on a server and not on the local machine. Plus if logging into a file is working before calling the thread, it should be working inside the thread method as well right? I mean if the thread is getting spawned correctly.

Comment: does the `StartJob` method otherwise work as intended?

Comment: @MongZhu, No, it seems like it is not getting called at all!

Comment: have you tried using a `BackgroundWorker` ?

Comment: @MongZhu,yes but it is not working as well!

Comment: I tried your code on an new project, for testing reasons I put `Debug.WriteLine("job done");` into `StartJob` and it works. I get the expected output in the Debug output window. Problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: @MongZhu, thanks for this! What could be the problem, any thoughts? Am I missing some setting or something which is causing it to ignore threading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120507/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-samar).